# Instance has no attribute _float_

Tags: python, class

I am learning about class construction in python 2.7.13 on windows. I am getting the error : Sales instance has no attribute __float_

Any hint how to make my code work? How to avoid this kind of error?
Below is my code

```
class Sales():
    # Sales predicts

    def __init__(self, df):
        # Each sales dataset has descriptive statistics.
        self.desc = df.describe()
        self.rows = len(df)
        self.cols = len(df.columns)
        self.counts = df['TARGET'].value_counts()
        self.plot = sns.countplot(x = 'TARGET', data = df, palette='hls')


    def sales_prob(self, df1, df2):
        """
        Function that computes logistic regression given a training and testing dataframes
        :param df1: historical dataframe (training)
        :param df2: monthly dataframe (testing)
        :return: df_out : dataframe containing predictions for the target 2
        """
        X_train0 = list(df1.loc[:, df1.columns != 'TARGET'])
        X_train = df1[X_train0]
        y_train = df1[['TARGET']]

        X_test0 = list(df2.loc[:, df2.columns != 'TARGET'])
        X_test = df2[X_test0]
        y_test = df2[['TARGET']]

        classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
        classifier.fit(self, X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
        y_pred2 =pd.DataFrame(classifier.predict_proba(self, X_test))
        y_pred2['prediction2'] = y_pred2[[2]]

        df_out = pd.merge(df2, y_pred2[['prediction2']], how = 'left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

        return (df_out)

# Example to use Sales class
venta = Sales(data1)
venta.desc
venta.cols

proba = venta.sales_prob(data1, data2)
```

This is my traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Documents\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2881, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       proba = venta.sales_prob(data1, data2)   File "", line 29, in sales_prob
>       classifier.fit(self, X_train, y_train.values.ravel())   File "C:\Documents\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py",
>   line 1173, in fit
>       order="C")   File "C:\Documents\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 521, in check_X_y
>       ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)   File "C:\Documents\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 382, in check_array
>       array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy) AttributeError: Sales instance has no attribute '**float**'
>   traceback.print_tb

Comment: Please write the full traceback.

Comment: that is the entire message that is printed when you run the program.

Comment: Just provide the full error message, the traceback is the part that tells you where in the code the error was raised (which would obviously be helpful)

Comment: Fundamentally, though, I suspect it is coming from passing `self` to the classifier: `classifier.fit(self, X_train, y_train.values.ravel())`... why do you think you can pass `self` here? `.fit` expects an *array*

Comment: i am getting the Error 'predict_proba() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)' when removing self to the classifier

Comment: Oh I got it, i had to remove self from `classifier.fit(self, X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
        y_pred2 =pd.DataFrame(classifier.predict_proba(self, X_test))`